# Android Load Many Images Efficiently

Tags: java, android, memory, imageview

I have a lot of PNG images contained in the various Drawable folders (Drawable-xhdpi, Drawable-mdpi, etc.) They are all relatively small (at most like 10KB) but at one point I need to load about 50 of them onto the screen. When I do this, it causes an OutOfMemoryError. Ideally, I would like to be able to load these images by simply calling setContentView once (the content view has a bunch of ImageViews with their src attribute already set to the corresponding images). That's what I'm doing now, but of course this isn't working because of the memory error. Besides reducing the size of the images, is there any way to prevent the OutOfMemoryError?

Comment: you can use some efficient image loading library like picasso: http://square.github.io/picasso/

Comment: are you loading them all at once or recycling them? check this out - https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html

Comment: you can increase the size of the heap by writing 
        "android:largeHeap="true" " in manifest file under application tag

Comment: astuter- I tried that but it caused a noticeable delay in loading the images on the bottom half of the screen. Ideally, I'd like to be able to somehow load all the images in the background before displaying any of them. Does picasso support something like that? Additionally, it requires setting each image individually at runtime, rather than in an XML file, right?

Comment: Amos- that looks like it could possibly be helpful, but I don't need the scrolling features offered by those classes; I want everything to be displayed on the same screen. I'm not sure if there's a more fitting way to do that, but I will definitely try that option out. Thanks!

Comment: Ravneet- I've done that as well and it still crashes on emulators, although that does allow it to run on real devices.

Comment: If you want to display them all on one screen you might want to draw them to a canvas object one by one and then add the canvas to the view. This way you do not need to keep the images in memory and only one canvas will be in memory.

Answer (score 1):

Avoid loading this number of images all at once,
instead you can load them in a `GridView` as described [here](http://square.github.io/picasso/).

Use [Picasso](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/display-bitmap.html#gridview) with `GridView` for memory efficiency

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup container) {
   ImageView imageView;
   if (convertView == null) { // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
      imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
      imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
      imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(
      LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
      } else {
         imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
      }
   // Load image into ImageView "using Picasso"         
   Picasso.with(mContext).load(imageResIds[position]).into(imageView);
   return imageView;
}
```